# Running PVC conduit in converted attic

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, attic-conversion

I have an attic that is semi-converted. I want to install eclectic outlets at 7 locations. I am wondering which conduit is better to use the PVC rigid one (pipes) or the flexible one. From what I could find the rigid one is mostly used for outdoor installations. Also is there any nice looking conduit that would be a good choice for this?

[image: The source of electricity is marked with thunder and the desired outlet locations with the X]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "semi converted"?   Will the conduit be surface mounted? While product recommendations are off topic here, I'll cheat just a bit and mention Wiremold conduit.  They have a system of parts for surface mount that look decent.

Comment: Where are you running the cables? Under floorboards, or exposed?

Comment: Pictures would be much more useful than the diagram

Comment: I am running the cables exposed. So it's going to be surface mounted.

Comment: One quick note for the future: when asking electrical questions here, most people will assume US/Canada based answers unless you otherwise specify your location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use PVC or "the flexible one". I'd use either:

- Metal Conduit

There are several types. EMT is the least expensive, and should be fine for attic use. A key advantage of metal conduit is that it provides a ground path, so that saves running a ground wire. An advantage or disadvantage, depending on your design preferences, is that it has an industrial look. Personally, I think metal conduit + metal boxes + metal faceplates is a great look. Definitely good for a workshop. But if this is a really finished room then it may seem out of place.

- Wiremold

This is a specific product made by Legrand. There may be other similar products out there. It looks more "finished" than regular PVC and metal, with everything from surface raceways (the conduit itself) to junction boxes, elbows, power strips and other accessories available. Short of running cables or conduit inside finished walls, this is the most "finished" look you're likely to find.

Comment: This sounds good. Is there any standard or code to say what is permitted and what not? Mostly concerning safety.

Comment: Yes, hundreds of pages. Called the NEC. New version every 3 years (currently 2020 but some states still on 2017 or older). So you have a lot to learn...

Comment: Actually, just checked and if you are actually in Macedonia then the details of the rules will be different. NEC is basically for US/Canada. Europe (and other parts of the world) have different rules. The *basic* concept of metal conduit is similar worldwide, but there are definitely regional variations. If you confirm your location then someone may provide more specific details for what is/isn't allowed in your area.

Comment: I'm in the EU actually. (old profile data, thanks for bringing that up)

Comment: Also, if you look at what locals have installed in recent years, that may give you an idea of what is easily available in your location, both materials and expertise.